# How can I POST values to and open an external site within Salesforce window?

Tags: visualforce, post

I want a tab that opens an external website within Salesforce window.  I need to POST values to it.

I tried creating a Visualforce page and using  it in a VF tab but even with using _target=self, the external site still fills the whole browser tab so it looks like you've left Salesforce.  I want it to look like it's within Salesforce.

Here's what I tried (I'm a Certified Admin but VF newbie btw :-) ):

[image: Here's the code that I tried:]

(sub question - how do you include code in a question?  I had to resort to using an image!!)

Thanks!

Comment: Code is formatted automatically if you indent each line with 4 spaces.  Leave a leading blank line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put your form in another page, in an iFrame? So you will have two apex pages

FormWrapper.page:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:iframe src="/apex/Form.page" height="800" />
</apex:page>
```

Form.page:

```
<apex:page>
  <form action="https:// etc etc etc
```

Then make the VF tab show FormWrapper.page. Then submitting the form should navigate in the iframe. If it works, you may want to check out the [documentation for apex:iframe](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_iframe.htm) to see how to set height, width etc.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, that's exactly what I needed.

I needed to add "showHeader="false" sidebar="false" " into the Form.page otherwise the form button was in a SF page nested within SF.

This was for a Community tab so I needed to use the full url of the Form.page in the 'src' of the iframe.

All working nicely now :-)